# KO bound value out of sync with dropdown

Tags: knockout.js

I'm running into this case where a dropdown's bound value observable isn't synced automatically when the dropdown is changed from a computable KO property.
It's a bit tricky because the dropdown is populated from a value selected in another dropdown, but to make this more clear I created this test fiddle which demonstrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/n3wjack/gzmb792p/

Here's how to simulate the issue:

- In the pet dropdown, select "Mozart", John's second pet. You'll see the 'selected pet' label update.
- Now choose Jane in the first dropdown. The second dropdown will update, showing Jane's pets.

The selected pet label is **not updated** to show the name of Jane's first pet.
If you make changes tot the pet dropdown, the value is updated again.
I can't guarantee the user will do this, so I'm not sure if the value will be correct.

So how do I fix this, or what am I doing wrong?

--

I'm also including the code below, cause apparently that's required.

JS:

```
var petOwners = [
    { name: "John", pets: ["Blacky","Mozart"] },
  { name: "Jane", pets: ["Polly", "Felix"]}
];

var viewModel = {

  availableOwners: ko.observableArray(petOwners),
  selectedOwner: ko.observable(),  

  selectedPet: ko.observable()
}

viewModel.availablePets = ko.computed(function(){
    console.log("** availablePets computed **")
    var result = [];
    if (viewModel.selectedOwner())
    {
        console.log(viewModel.selectedOwner());
        result = viewModel.selectedOwner().pets;      
    }

    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }, this);

viewModel.peekPet = function (){
    document.getElementById("peekoutput").innerHTML += "selectedPet = " + viewModel.selectedPet.peek() + "</br>";
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="foreach:availableOwners, value:selectedOwner">
  <option data-bind="text: name, value: $data"></option>
</select>
<i>
( selected: <span data-bind="text: selectedOwner().name"></span> )
</i>

<p>
This dropdown shows the pets of the owner, selected in the above dropdown.
</p>
<select data-bind="foreach:availablePets, value: selectedPet">
  <option data-bind="text: $data, value: $data"></option>
</select>

<p>
<i> 
Selected pet: <span data-bind="text: selectedPet"></span>
</i>
</p>
<p>
The selected pet however doesn't update to be in sync with the first pet in the dropdown, when you change the owner dropdown. :(
</p>

<p>
<button data-bind="click: peekPet">Peek selected pet</button>
</p>

<code id="peekoutput">
</code>
```

Comment: You should use the `options` binding rather than `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is subscribe to the change of the selected owner:

```
 var viewModel = {
  availableOwners: ko.observableArray(petOwners),
  selectedOwner: ko.observable(),  
  selectedPet: ko.observable()
 }

 viewModel.selectedOwner.subscribe(function(){
    if(viewModel.selectedOwner().pets.length > 0) {
        viewModel.selectedPet(viewModel.selectedOwner().pets[0]);
    }
 });
```

[UPDATED JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gzmb792p/17/)

There is also an alternative binding for the select that will sync the selected with the collection without a subscription:

```
<select data-bind="options: availablePets, optionsText: $data, optionsValue: $data, value: selectedPet"></select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gzmb792p/18/

Comment: Using the options binding works indeed. Interesting. I was used to using that foreach syntax but apparently KO seems to behave different than when you use that options binding. I guess that's what it's meant for.
The foreach works as long as you keep it simple. But in my case with the 2nd dropdown depening on the 1st things went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

here is a different approach. petowners becomes an array of objects.  then you use the options binding. here is the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/22/

javascript

```
var petOwners = [{
  name: "John",
  pets: ["Blacky", "Mozart"]
}, {
  name: "Jane",
  pets: ["Polly", "Felix"]
}];

function petOwner(data) {
  var self = this;
  this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  this.selectedPet = ko.observable('');
  this.pets = ko.observableArray(data.pets);
}

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.petOwners = ko.observableArray('');
  this.selectedPetOwner = ko.observable('');
}


var vm = new viewModel();


(function($) {
  ko.applyBindings(vm); //bind the knockout model
  $.each(petOwners, function(i, item) {
    vm.petOwners.push(new petOwner(item));
  });
  console.log(ko.toJS(vm));
})(jQuery);
```

html

```
choose a pet owner:
<select data-bind="options: petOwners,
                       optionsText: 'name',
                       value: selectedPetOwner,
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>

<div data-bind="with: selectedPetOwner">
  Choose a pet:
  <select data-bind="options: pets, value: selectedPet"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because when it's refreshing the list, you are not selecting any pet. By default it shows the first one but it doesn't mean that he is selected.

You can add an instruction to actually select the first one in the list:

```js
viewModel.availablePets = ko.computed(function(){
   console.log("** availablePets computed **")
   var result = [];

   if (viewModel.selectedOwner())
   {
      console.log(viewModel.selectedOwner());
      result = viewModel.selectedOwner().pets;

      //something like this to mark your first pet as selected. 
      viewModel.selectedPet(result[0]);    
   }

   console.log(result);
   return result;
}, this);
```

Comment: tried that as well, and oddly enough it doesn't work. I updated the fiddle, you can even see in the log that it sets the value, but the binding doesn't update: https://jsfiddle.net/n3wjack/gzmb792p/15/

Comment: This might not work because it rejects setting the selected pet to something that isn't even an option yet, because the available pets aren't updated until the result is returned.

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking something along that line too. It seems to refuse the edit indeed.